# Notation question: Matrix expectation value?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, random-variables, expected-value

I see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Chernoff_bound#Matrix_Chernoff_I) the following statement

Consider a finite sequence $\left\{\mathbf{X}_{k}\right\}$ of independent, random, self-adjoint matrices with dimension $d$. Define

$$\mu_{\min }=\lambda_{\min }\left(\sum_{k} \mathbb{E} \mathbf{X}_{k}\right) \quad \text { and } \quad \mu_{\max }=\lambda_{\max }\left(\sum_{k} \mathbb{E} \mathbf{X}_{k}\right)$$

What is the meaning of $\mathbb{E} \mathbf{X}_{k}$? Normally, this is the expectation value but here, I don't understand it. We have $\lambda_{\max}(\cdot)$ so the $\sum_{k} \mathbb{E} \mathbf{X}_{k}$ itself is a matrix which means $\mathbb{E} \mathbf{X}_{k}$ is a matrix. So what is it?

Comment: It’s the expected value. This is defined formally as a certain integral and that integral makes sense for vector-valued random variables, and in particular matrix-valued random variables.

Comment: Could you add the name of this definition or the integral? And intuitively, is it correct that $X_k$ is a random (matrix) variable and $\mathbb{E}X_k$ is the average of many instances of $X_k$?

Comment: Yes, the law of large numbers continues to hold for vector-valued random variables, basically by applying it pointwise to each coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). Explicitly, a random matrix $X$ is a matrix each of whose entries $X_{ij}$ is a random variable, and the expected value $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is the matrix with entries the pointwise expected values $\mathbb{E}(X_{ij})$.

Abstractly, a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) $X$ defined on a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega, P)$ has an expectation defined by the integral $\int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, dP(\omega)$. This integral makes sense for vector-valued $X$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (where it is just the pointwise integral of each coefficient of $X$) and more generally for $X$ taking values in a [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral).